# Remove the indentation of the footnote marker

Tags: footnotes

How to remove the following indentation (selected red) of the footnote marker? 
[image]

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}


\author{Имя Автора}
\title{1.1 Наш первый документ}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Привет, мир!

\section*{Введение}
m quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi\footnote{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error si} optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudi 

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you load the [footmisc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/) package with the option `hang` to achieve your objective. The distance between the footnote marker and the start of the footnote text is determined by the parameter `\footnotemargin`.

The following screenshot shows just the footnote produced by the MWE given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{1em}  % default value: 1.8em

\begin{document}

m quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi.\footnote{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error si} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: So many answers to my question :) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

At last it depends how the footnote should look.  One way is to let the footnote number stand alone and use a left-right-justified block for the footnotetext.

You can get that with the following MWE (to change the footnote please see the lines between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[%
  english,
% russian
]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%   \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
    \footnotesize}%
    \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother

\author{Имя Автора}
\title{1.1 Наш первый документ}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Привет, мир!

\section*{Введение}
m quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, 
cum soluta nobis est eligendi\footnote{Sed 
  ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error si.  Optio, cumque nihil 
  impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis 
  voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.} 
optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudi 

\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using a package like `footmisc.sty` is definitely a good idea, but for this kind of change, there is also a nice snippet in `classes.pdf` (try `texdoc classes`):

> ### 8.4 Footnotes
>
> An example of what can be achieved is given by the
>   following piece of TEX code.
>
> ```
> \newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
>   \@setpar{\@@par
>     \@tempdima = \hsize
>     \advance\@tempdima-10pt
>     \parshape \@ne 10pt \@tempdima}%
>   \par
>   \parindent 1em\noindent
>   \hbox to \z@{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
> ```
>
> The effect of this definition is that all lines of the footnote are
>   indented by 10pt, while the first line of a new paragraph is indented
>   by 1em. To change these dimensions, just substitute the desired value
>   for '10pt' (in both places) or '1em'. The mark is flushright against
>   the footnote.

You can adjust the code acc. to your needs; here an uglified example for demonstration:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \@setpar{\@@par
    \@tempdima=\hsize
    \advance\@tempdima by -15pt
    \parshape \@ne 15pt \@tempdima}%
  \par
  \parindent 1em\noindent
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \hss\hbox to 15pt{%
      {\color{blue}\itshape\@thefnmark}\color{magenta}\bfseries.\hss
    }%
  }%
  #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Привет, мир!
\section*{Введение}
m quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore,
cum soluta nobis est eligendi\footnote{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis
  iste natus error si.  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus
  error, si.  \par Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error
  si.}  optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime
placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor
repellendus. \par\vfill
\noindent Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum
necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudi
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can load the KOMA-Script package `scrextend` and use KOMA's `\deffootnote` for customizing the footnote appearance:

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
}
```

`\deffootnote` works like this:

```
\deffootnote[width of mark]{indent of footnote text}
                           {paragraph indent in a footnote}
                           {definition of the mark}
```

Inside `definition of the mark` you can use `\thefootnotemark` in order to refer to the actual mark.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
}


\author{Имя Автора}
\title{1.1 Наш первый документ}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Привет, мир!

\section*{Введение}
m quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum
soluta nobis est eligendi\footnote{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus
  error si} optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat,
facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor
repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum
necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which parameter do I use to adjust the space between the footnote marker and the footnote text?