# How to adjust space between footnote marker and footnote text using scrextend?

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

A follow-up question regarding [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270688/11195) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270412/remove-the-indentation-of-the-footnote-marker?rq=1): Suppose I load the KOMA-Script package `scrextend` and use KOMA's `\deffootnote` to customize the footnote appearance:

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
}
```

Apparently `\deffootnote` works like this:

```
\deffootnote[width of mark]{indent of footnote text}
                           {paragraph indent in a footnote}
                           {definition of the mark}
```

**My question is:** Which parameter(s) can I use to adjust only the space between the footnote marker and the footnote text (while keeping all of the footnote text left-aligned unless I start a new paragraph within the footnote or indent manually)?

**To clarify:** I want to adjust the spacing between the footnote marker and the first word of the footnote. Adjusting mark width just moves both of them together. Adjusting indent only affects the first words of subsequent lines. And adjusting parindent only affects the first words of subsequent paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Image taken from the KOMA-Script manual to visualize the parameters in

`\deffootnote[mark width]{indent}{parindent}{definition}`

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't understand what the desired result looks like.

Maybe you want:

[image]

Then use the same value for *mark width*, *indent* and the width of the box in *definition*. Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext\par\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

But if you set *indent* to 0pt

```latex
\deffootnote[1.5em]{0em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
}
```

you will get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to adjust the spacing between the footnote marker and the first word of the footnote. Adjusting mark width just moves both of them together. Adjusting indent, as your example shows, only affects the first words of subsequent lines. And adjusting parindent only affects the first words of subsequent paragraphs.